# Backbone - View not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, jsfiddle

I'm new to backbone and trying to make a book library app. While running this code, it is not showing the template.
This is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    Name:<input type='text' id='name'/><br>
    Author:<input type='text' id='auth'/><br>
    Keyword:<input type='text' id='keyword'/><br><br>
    <button id="add">Add</button>
</form>
<div id='book_list'>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script  id="bookTemplate" type="text/template">
    <ul>
        <li><%= name %></li>
        <li><%= auth %></li>
        <li><%= keyword %></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is script.js

```
$(function(){
    var bookmodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
                name:'temp',
                auth:'meee',
                keyword:'nonee'
            },
});
var booklist = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:bookmodel
});
var bookview= Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'div',
    className: 'bookContainer',
    template: _.template( $('#bookTemplate').html()),
    events:{
        'click .delete':'deleteBook'
    },
    render : function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    deleteBook: function(){
        this.model.destroy();
        this.remove();
    }
});
var library = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: bookmodel,

    initialize: function( initialBooks ) {

        $el='#book_list';
        var one=new bookmodel({name:'ankur 1',auth:'asdf 1',keyword:'asdfkasdf 1'});
        var two=new bookmodel({name:'ankur 2',auth:'asdf 2',keyword:'asdfkasdf 2'});
        var bookcoll= [one,two];
        this.collection = new booklist(bookcoll);
        this.render();
    },

    render:function(){
        this.collection.each(function (item){
        var k= new bookview({model:item});
        this.$el.append(k.render().el);
        },this);

    },
});
var xyz= new library();
})
```

Also, when i'm trying to code like this:

```
var library = Backbone.View.extend({  
model: bookmodel,  
$el:'#book_list';   
.....  //rest of the code
)};  
var xyz= new library();
```

Then,it is leading to : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function, at line
    `var xyz= new library();`

Comment: In your library declaration that semi colon should be a comma after `#book_list`

Comment: Also in your `initialize` function you have `$el:"#book_list";` which should be something like `this.el = "#book_list";`

Comment: Yes, there is a comma, i missplaced it here,

Comment: Still same scene.. template not rendring.

Comment: Ok thanx.. i'm waiting..

Comment: Ok I recreated your error in a fiddle then fixed it in a different one.  Good luck in learning backbone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to recreate your error in jsfiddle by using their underscore library backbone loader.  It wasn't an issue with your code.  The following fiddle shows your same error:

http://jsfiddle.net/32tsA/

While this one works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/BympL/

The issue was with how you had the fiddle set up in my estimation.

I did make some minor changes to fix up capitalization and some best practices with Backbone:

```
var Bookmodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
                name:'temp',
                auth:'meee',
                keyword:'nonee'
    }
});

var Booklist = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Bookmodel
});

var Bookview = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'div',
    className: 'bookContainer',
    template: _.template( $('#bookTemplate').html()),
    events:{
        'click .delete':'deleteBook'
    },
    render : function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    deleteBook: function(){
        this.model.destroy();
        this.remove();
    }
});

var one=new Bookmodel({name:'ankur 1',auth:'asdf 1',keyword:'asdfkasdf 1'});
var two=new Bookmodel({name:'ankur 2',auth:'asdf 2',keyword:'asdfkasdf 2'});
var bookcoll = [one,two];

var mybooks = new Booklist(bookcoll);
var Library = Backbone.View.extend({
    render:function(){
        this.collection.each(function (item){
        var k= new Bookview({model:item});
        this.$el.append(k.render().el);
        },this);
    },
});
var xyz = new Library({collection: mybooks, el: "#book_list"});
xyz.render();
```

I named the classes with capital case, removed the initialization of the models from your view (views should be told their models not create their models), and abstracted the el declaration from the Library declaration (so you can reuse the view in a different place).

Comment: Thanx for your fiddle, it's working, but i'm still unable to understand why it was not working earlier..

Comment: Here is another one which should prove to you that it had nothing to do with your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/wUwp8/  That fiddle has nothing but a single call to `new Backbone.View();` and still fails.  The issue is somehow in the way that jsfiddle was ordering underscore and backbone and jquery.

Comment: thanx for your help Andy, i wonder if you can give some suggestion to avoid such problem in future.

Comment: If you want to use jsfiddle as your Backbone sandbox then I would make a working basic setup from which you fork your new projects.  The way I was able to make my example work properly was by using JQuery in the frameworks dropdown, and adding underscore then backbone in the external resources section.  For the links I used cdnjs.  Feel free to fork the following mostly empty but working fiddle for backbone play:
http://jsfiddle.net/mY2Rw/

Comment: And if i want to develop offline, means using editor like notepad++ and downloaded library files of jquer,underscore and backbone..

Comment: Yeah, if you load your libraries in the right order you'll be fine.  If you want to make sure that the order of the loading isn't an issue (and generally have a clean code base) look into requirejs.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and it seemed fine. I dont know exactly whats in script.js but try including your template above your script.js file. It probably can't find your template at the point it was running